# Access return value from different Vue component ("1= X, 2=Y, 3=X-Y")

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm a bit new to Vue.js and trying to build a simple calculator.

I decided to break the app down into 3 components: revenues, cost and profits.
The user is supposed to make his input in "revenues" and "cost" and then "profits" should be calculated automatically.

The console logs the correct results for the "revenue" and "cost" components. But how do I re-use or pass their **return** values into the "profits" component? Like this:

```
let calculatedProfits = revenuesFirst - developmentCost;
```

All code is in one *app.js* file.

The revenue-input component looks like this:

```
Vue.component('revenues-input', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      licenseFee: "100",
      potentialClients: "1000"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    revenuesFirst: function(e) {
      let rFirst = this.licenseFee * this.potentialClients;
      return rFirst;
    },
  template: ...
});
```

The cost-input component:

```
// Cost Input Component
Vue.component('cost-input', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      costRate: "160",
      numberOfExperts: "1"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    developmentCost: function(e) {
      let dc = this.costRate * this.numberOfExperts; 
      return dc;
    }
  },
  template: ...
});
```

I thought that I might put the *computed* variables from the first two components as *data* in the last component, but that's not working.

My result output component:

```
// Result Output Component
Vue.component('result-output', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      revenuesFirst: "",
      developmentCost: ""
   }
  },
  computed: {
    calculatedProfits: function(e) {
      let cp = this.revenuesFirst - this.developmentCost; 
      return cp;
    }
  },
  template: ...
})
```

And finally the Vue instance:

```
//Vue instance
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

I appreciate any input, thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use a parent component that wraps all of these and defines the data there. you can use 2-way bindings to communicate between the child and parent component, and make the parent component the single source of truth. you can also use a `vuex` store, instead.

Comment: You would basically have to $emit everything to parents then down to children. This is exactly why you'd want to implement Vuex.

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy and Arc for your guidance. Unfortunately all those concepts are new to me and I don't yet understand from your numerous suggestions which one to pick. Additionally I found yesterday an interesting article about "props" in order to pass variables between components: [link](https://michaelnthiessen.com/vue-props-ultimate-guide) - I guess I will start looking into all of those possibilities :)